# Typescript: destructure entire props object and provide default values using ES6

Tags: typescript

Found an working example of having a default for properties:

```js
const defaultDisabled = '';
const Greet: React.FC<Props> = ({ disabled = defaultDisabled }: Props) => (
// ...
```

But I don't want to create a separate object for each default value.

How to add a default object for the entire props object? The following gives an error:

```js
interface Props {
  label: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
}
const defaultProps = { disabled: false };

// Parsing error: "," expected
const Greet: React.FC<Props> = ({ label, disabled } = defaultProps: Props) => (
// ...
```

Comment: But your function always requires `label` to be provided so there's no reason to default it since it is guaranteed by TS to always be a `string`. Defaulting would make sense for `disabled` since it is optional.

Comment: Sharp observation! My component has more props, this was just an example. But you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with assigning defaultProps as in the snippet

```
interface Props  {
  label: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

const Greet: React.FC<Props> = ({ label }) => {
  return <div>{label}</div>;
};

Greet.defaultProps = { label: "" };
```

If you do this it will even type check the defaultProps object, so you cant assign anything that isnt mentioned in Props

Comment: Aha. This works. I missed this one since [typescript-cheatsheets](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#typing-defaultprops) advises against using React.FC in combination with defaultProps. And read here that [defaultProps was dying](https://medium.com/@matanbobi/react-defaultprops-is-dying-whos-the-contender-443c19d9e7f1). But this indeed works fine. Thanks!

Comment: its not dying there is just alternative, can you mark it as answer if it works? so I can get some meaningless internet points? :D

Comment: He mentions good arguments on using ES6. But I wasn't able to have the props type checked with it. I also went down a getProps rabbit hole, [mentioned by Martin Hochel](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-typescript-and-defaultprops-dilemma-ca7f81c661c7). But that's an article from 2018, so might be outdated.